# Redshift copy command loaded the data into table but there are no records found in the stl_load_commits table

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I have loaded 100+ tables using the copy command all the times it is working fine and everything is good. The data is in the table and I am able to query the data but only one table entry is not found in the stl_load_commits table.
Is there any specific reason for this?.

Comment: Are you looking at the stl_load_commits using the Admin account? Can you see those loads on the AWS Redshift Console's `Loads` tab?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Admin account and see the load(copy command) in the Redshift console and data in the table also.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Can you help me by answering, Why you are querying stl_load_commits ?

Please do tell me if i have understood you correctly or not -

You have SUCCESSFULLY Loaded data across 100+ tables . Right ?
Successful Load means all data has been copied without any rejection ( Please check stl_load_errors if any ).

But you are unable to find any entry in the table stl_load_commits. Right ?

is that correct ?

If that's Correct, (IMPORTANT DOCUMENTATION -  [AWS DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html) ) .
Besides, the things that might be relevant here are  -

1. Only *Superusers* can see all rows. Other users can only see Data Loads Done by them. - i.e 
   The *db-admin user* can see all data loads information
   **WHILE** the *write-user* can only see data loads info. done by it or below users
   **AND** the *read/dev user* can only see data loads info. done by it.
   So, please use the same user to query this table as was used to copy data.
2. It  shows how many records were loaded per file but it does not provide a simple way to associate the load to the table being loaded (only query_id is provided)

Comment: Let me clarify on this. I am superuser and I have full access to Redshift cluster. we are building the framework and as part of the use case, I am checking the stl_load_commits tables. I have loaded 100+ tables successfully means all the data is copied without errors. My question is there any scenario where Redshift will not insert the records into stl_load_commits?.

Comment: Ohh I see, I dont think there are any such cases but will have to check. Previously, there was some issue going with csv's but that is resolved now. Can you give me some more details like - How are you loading/Copying ?, what kind of connection postgresql or jdbc/odbc  etc etc.

Comment: has anyone found scenarios where this occurs?   what is the persistence on this table (it seems like records are purged at intervals, or no?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems Redshift has a bug. At least this was the case in our situation:
The source file being loaded had no 'end of line' character at the end of the file.

When this happens, no entry is made in the stl_load_commits table, even though the file is loaded into the table without error.

Check the source file that was missing in the stl table, and see what symbols were at the very end of the file.